# Swagger for Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, swagger

Has anyone used a swagger tool with Kotlin?

In our organization, we have create most of our REST services using Java and SpringMVC (@RestController classes). We have used springfox to generate the Swagger API documentation. The swagger JSON representation is also used to automatically feed a searchable service catalog, so the swagger format for service metadata is important to us.

Some dev teams are now beginning to use Kotlin. We're looking for recommendations or comments related to using springfox or other swagger lib with Kotlin.

Answer (score 7):

Here is sample spring boot app with swagger:

```
@RestController
class MyController {
    @ApiOperation(value = "doc header...", notes = "detailed doc...")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/double", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
    fun doubleValue(number: Int) = 2 * number
}


@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    fun api(): Docket {
        return Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
    }
}
```

dependencies are

```
compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.7.0")
compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0")
```

If you browse http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html it is all there...

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar requirement. As a result I created a [template project](https://github.com/cdimascio/kotlin-swagger-spring-functional-template) that integrates Kotlin, Webflux, and Swagger. It provides interactive API doc and automatic request validation.

See here -> https://github.com/cdimascio/kotlin-swagger-spring-functional-template

Validation is functional. It's used as such:

```
validate.request(req) {
  // Do stuff e.g. return a list of names 
  ok().body(Mono.just(listOf("carmine", "alex", "eliana")))
}
```

with body

```
validate.request(req).withBody(User::class.java) { body ->
  // Note that body is deserialized as User!
  // Now you can do stuff. 
  // For example, lets echo the request as the response 
  ok().body(Mono.just(body))
}
```

It utilizes openapi 2 and 3 validation provided by atlassian.